# Issue in Genymotion emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I have downloaded, install and configure Genymotion properly. But now when I try to run genymotion it is giving an error as shown in image

[image]

What's the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to virtual box --> Preference --> Network --> Hot Only Network
right click on vboxnet0 and edit the IPv4 Address to 192.168.56.2
It will work.

Comment: @user3193299 : Please accept the answer if it works for you :)